# Extend magento core controller (Checkout/OnepageController)

Tags: magento, controller, overriding, extend

I am having problems while overriding a core controller. I want to add a new function but it only works if I do it in the core file (code/core/checkout/controllers/onepagecontroller.php).

I have followed some post, but it's not working. Some of them are:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/32979/P0/
- http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/03/override-controllers-in-magento.html
- www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller

(I can't add more links, sorry)

I don't know what is happening... maybe you can help me ;).

I'm using magento 1.5 and I have this 3 files:

---

local -> Arias -> CoreExtended -> etc -> config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Arias_CoreExtended>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Arias_CoreExtended>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Arias_CoreExtended before="Mage_Checkout">Arias_CoreExtended_Checkout</Arias_CoreExtended>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

---

app -> etc -> modules -> Arias_CoreExtended.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Arias_CoreExtended>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </Arias_CoreExtended>
    </modules>
</config>
```

---

local -> Arias -> CoreExtended -> controllers -> Checkout -> OnepageController.php

```
<?php

require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';

class Arias_CoreExtended_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
{
    public function collectAction()
    {
        echo 'WTF?';
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "This controller has been overridden.";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time, regards.

Answer (score 1):

I would first mirror the same directory structure of the controller you are overwriting, so in this case change: `local/Arias/CoreExtended/controllers/Checkout/OnepageController.php` to `local/Arias/CoreExtended/controllers/OnepageController.php`

You should lowercase your namespace/module name and you need to remove `_Checkout` as it is overwriting the controllers in general, and will look up any that exist in the module to use them instead if not fall back to standard. The correct code would be:

```
<arias_coreextended before="Mage_Checkout">Arias_CoreExtended</arias_coreextended>
```

I have used this exact setup with success to overwrite the Onepage controller!

Answer (score 0):

I would try lower casing your namespace/modulename like so:

`<arias_coreextended before="Mage_Checkout">Arias_CoreExtended_Checkout</arias_coreextended>`

Comment: It doesn't work. Something more that I could try? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is mostly correct @satumo. The only thing you should change is this line

```
<Arias_CoreExtended before="Mage_Checkout">Arias_CoreExtended</Arias_CoreExtended>
```

So your full configuration have to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Arias_CoreExtended>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Arias_CoreExtended>
    </modules>  

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Arias_CoreExtended before="Mage_Checkout">Arias_CoreExtended</Arias_CoreExtended>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```