# Magento 1.7 - How to extend core controller

Tags: php, magento

I'm attempting to extend the OnepageController with this setup:

app/etc/modules/Custom_Checkout.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Checkout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Custom_Checkout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/local/Custom/Checkout/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Checkout>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Custom_Checkout>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <custom_checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Custom_Checkout</custom_checkout>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

app/local/Custom/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php

```
require_once("Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php");

class Custom_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
    echo "Index overidden";
    }

}
```

I've seen these:
[Extend magento core controller (Checkout/OnepageController)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918499/extend-magento-core-controller-checkout-onepagecontroller)

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller

Plus some more that I can't post, but none of the above methods seem to work. It just doesn't overwrite the controller.

Any ideas on why this isn't overwriting?

Comment: Your `app/local/` path should be `app/code/local`

Comment: I had same problem and after debugging I found that there was another installed module which already overloaded OnepageCntroller.php, which was the reason otherwise correct code wasn't even loaded. It's good idea to also check other installed modules.

Answer (score 1):

There are, unfortunately, myriad things that could be wrong here, and not enough information in your post to track them down.  Instead of an answer, here's a debugging tip.  Take a look at the `_validateControllerClassName` function.

```
protected function _validateControllerClassName($realModule, $controller)
{
    $controllerFileName = $this->getControllerFileName($realModule, $controller);
    if (!$this->validateControllerFileName($controllerFileName)) {
        return false;
    }

    $controllerClassName = $this->getControllerClassName($realModule, $controller);
    if (!$controllerClassName) {
        return false;
    }

    // include controller file if needed
    if (!$this->_includeControllerClass($controllerFileName, $controllerClassName)) {
        return false;
    }

    return $controllerClassName;
}
```

Each `return false` is a state where Magento may decide to not use your controller class for a request.  Try adding some logging or `var_dump`ing of the `$controllerFileName`, `$controllerClassName`, both inside and outside the if statements. That's usually enough to point to the small mistake in file path name or class (case, missing character, etc) to fic your module.

If you don't see any information at all related to `Custom_Checkout`, that means Magento can't see your module, and you should start debugging that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to have the correct case. Instead of:

```
<custom_checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Custom_Checkout</custom_checkout>
```

It should spell:

```
<Custom_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Custom_Checkout</Custom_Checkout>
```