# Different checkout pages based on product category in Magento

Tags: magento, onepage-checkout

I am new to Magento .So please forgive me if I am asking something silly.

I am working on a Magento shop where I have a requirement that when I select some product in certain category say X, then I am redirected to one page checkout where I have default shipping method and do not want any payment method. i.e. Skip shipping and payment method step in chekout.

Whereas if I click some other categories then I get redirected to onepage checkout with shipping and payment option.

So basically what I need in form of code is -

```
   if(category==X)
             then Checkout without Shipping and payment method
  else
    Checkout with Shipping and Payment options.
```

As far as I have explored the magento structure , it is far too complex then other CMS. I am not able to even find files where i have to make changes in code. Anybody out there who can guide me for right approach toward the solution? Or is there any extension which fulfills such requirement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, create the new payment method for the category (and shipping method if you need that too).

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module

Then I would probably extend the controller, though you probably could also use an observer.

- [Extend magento core controller (Checkout/OnepageController)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918499/extend-magento-core-controller-checkout-onepagecontroller)

Keep in mind that the customer may have products from another category in their cart, and what to do in that case.